# Return the x-th largest element from a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to write a function `returnMlargest` that takes two arguments: a list `L`, and a number `m`. It returns the `m`-th largest number in that list. Assume that all elements in the list are different.

For example if I do `returnMlargest([6,2,5,4,3,7], 4)`,
it would return the 4th largest element from that list, which is 4.

I know how to code it if I sort the list first.  However, I want to know how can I do it without sorting the list.  I have to write a while loop or nested loop for this.

Please!  This is not a homework or assignment!  This is practice test for the final!  I know I am noob in programming because my question might not be good.  But hey!  People are not born as  programming geniuses!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Step one would be to write some code.

Comment: If this is for a final exam, it's all the more reason for you to be able to go through this yourself. IanAuld gave you some great pseudocode.

Comment: It's okay to be new. Code out what you think should work and if it doesn't work (you might surprise yourself) post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would say sorting the list would be the most efficient way to do this.

But, if you want to use two loops, you can do something like this:

```
int returnMlargest(int[] array, int m){

    int tempLargest, indexLargest;

    for(int x=0; x < m ; x++){ //remove m-1 of the largest elements

        tempLargest = indexLargest = 0; //reset largest counter

        for(int y=0; y< array.length; y++){

            if(array[y] > tempLargest){
                tempLargest = array[y];
                indexLargest = y;
            }
        }
        if( x == m - 1)
            return tempLargest; //result found

        //remove largest value from array, and repeat
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not Python lol

Comment: ha, woops! missed that :-|

Answer (score 1):

To help you along here is some psuedo code

```
def return_m_largest(a_list, m):
    make a copy of a_list  # unless it's okay to mutate the list
    for _ in range(m - 1):
        find the max and get rid of it
    return the highest number in the list
```

This will be very inefficient for large lists but as I suspect this is homework it likely won't be tested with very large lists. But if you can get this working you should be able to optimize it if you want/need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
def returnMlargest(l, M):
    cc = compile(';'.join(['list.remove(l, max(l))']*M), 'abc', 'single')
    eval(cc)
    for i in range(1):
        for i in range(1):
            pass
        return max(l)
```

> > > returnMlargest([1,2,4,3,7,6,5], 3)
> > >       4

nb. *M*th largest uses 0 based counting here, so in my example, *7* is the 0th largest number, so *4* is the 3rd largest number.

It doesn't explicitly sort the list, and it does technically include a nested loop (although it might get optimised out).

This isn't a homework answer (it would fail), this is a practise answer because I've never used 'compile' before and `eval()` wouldn't work directly on multiline statements.

Also the real answer to your question is contained within my answer. `I want to know how can I do it without sorting the list` well `look for the largest number and get rid of it, M times over`.